# Move UIView above UITableView when user Scrolls Down

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have n `UIView` above my `UITableView`. 
I would like to have the `UIView` moves up as if it is "pushed" by the `UITableView` when user scrolls.

I am wondering how do we create an effect like this?

[SCREENSHOT - Before User Scrolls](http://s13.postimg.org/6169cvn4n/IMG_0356.png)

[SCREENSHOT - After user Scrolls, Please notice the UIView above it (Offers, Discover, Most Booked)](http://s2.postimg.org/rf1suh0ah/IMG_0357.png)

Comment: Why not just insert the `UIView` as the tableview's header (or as a section header) instead of a UIView above the `UITableview`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view with 3 buttons needs to be taken as the header view of table. Take the outlet of that view.

```
[tableView setHeaderView:yourView];
```

You need to set this in the viewDidLoad of your view controller.